# Add object to ManyToMany field on save in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm looking to add an item to a manytomany field in a django model. Currently the new tag object is being created but it just isn't being added to `MyModel` when I call save in the admin. I'm not getting any errors from my code, any thoughts?

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.tags.count() == 0):
            tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(text=get_word())
            tag.save()
            self.tags.add(tag)

        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How are you using this in the admin? How are you entering the tag text? And what is `get_word?`

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm just using the django admin to enter my tag text. I'm also using it to create and save changes using my models. The get_word() just returns a string based on some other logic which isn't quite relevant. From what I understand, m2m fields are saved after the model is saved. It looks like I'm going to need to figure out a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

On the first you have to save MyModel instance and next use self.tags.add(tag)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # saving MyModel instance

        tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(text=get_word())
        tag.save()
        self.tags.add(tag) # adding m2m to saved instance MyModel

        return self
```

Comment: Thanks Slawek, I'm still having no success. After further research I discovered that what I am doing is not possible because many to many fields are saved after the model is saved.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add some values to a ManyToMany field you could use a post_save signal

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class MyModel(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def update_related_doc_sync(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # get or create Tag - no need to call .save()
    tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(text=get_word())
    # add tag to M2M field
    instance.tags.add(tag)
```